# Finding rows that are not duplicate

Tags: db2

I have two DB2 tables.

Table 1, called `EmployeeFile`

`EmployeeFile` has the following columns: `EMP_ID, FNAME, LNAME, DOB`

The data looks like this:

```
   EMP_ID, FNAME, LNAME, DOB
 - GB2342, John,  Smith, 1970-12-10
 - L3243C, Jane,  Jones, 1969-11-09
```

Table 2, called `OriginalData`

`OriginalData` has the following columns: `INTERNAL_ID, FNAME, LNAME, DOB`.

The data looks like this:

```
   INTERNAL_ID, FNAME, LNAME,    DOB
 - 6575678588,  Jane,  Jones,    1969-11-09
 - 1232145564,  Rob,   Mitchell, 1968-10-08
 - 3452345345,  John,  Smith,    1970-12-10
 - 6786478568,  John,  Smith,    1970-12-10
```

I want to show all rows of `EmployeeFile` for which the `(FNAME, LNAME, DOB)` combination occurs only once in `OriginalData`.

For example, if I ran the query on the example dataset shown above, it should return just the following row:

- Jane, Jones, 1969-11-09

I don't want 'John Smith' because although he exists in `EmployeeFile`, his `(FNAME, LNAME, DOB)` combination occurs twice in `OriginalData`.

I don't want 'Rob Mitchell' because he doesn't exist in `EmployeeFile`.

**Question**

How do I do this?

The only way I can think of is immensely ugly: Concatenate `(FNAME, LNAME, DOB)` (with some delimiter like ~) from both tables, do a join on that column, do a group by having `count(that concatenated column) = 1`, then do another select on `EmployeeFile`, selecting only those rows where the `(FNAME, LNAME, DOB)` match the parsed substrings of that concatenated string!

Comment: You don't need any concatenation as you can join tables on multiple columns; don't see why you need "another select on EmployeeFile". This leaves you with a `group by`, which is not ugly at all.

Comment: You could use a correlated EXISTS of course (without a GROUP BY) if you wanted. GROUP BY solution seems straight forward though.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ "combination occurs only once" -- how would you formulate the `exists` for this? You'd need a `not exists` too, which would probably be pretty inefficient.

Comment: @mustaccio exactly. With a `not exists` inside the `exists` subquery ;)

Comment: @mustaccio you are probably right about performanc but the devil ia always in the details. If the `EmployeeFile` table is very small and the `OriginalData` huge, I'd prefer a doubly correllated EXISTS/NOT EXISTS query (that would be evaluated only for every row of the small table) than a GROUP BY on the huge table (that the straightforward solution might do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
select e.* 
from EmployeeFile e
inner join
(
  select FNAME, LNAME, DOB
  from OriginalData
  group by FNAME, LNAME, DOB
  having count(1) = 1
) o
on (e.FNAME, e.LNAME, e.DOB) = (o.FNAME, o.LNAME, o.DOB)
```